# Erlang parse_transform second parameter

Tags: erlang, parse-transform

When defining a `parse_transform`, the function has [two parameters](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_id_trans.html):

```
parse_transform(FormsIn, Options) -> FormsOut
```

What is the meaning of the `Options` parameter? I'm trying to define additional options for transforming.

Comment: Have you checked out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2522574/58129?

Answer (score 2):

The second arg in the `parse_transform` function is the list of options to the compiler. They are both the explicit options in the compile call and some default options added by the compiler. The compiler ignores options it does no recognise so it it possible to pass specific options into the `parse_transform` function.